# Can I convert a dict to a url?

Tags: python-2.7, url, urlparse

For instance I have the following url pattern:

```
url_pattern = {
    "scheme": "http",
    "netloc": "for.example.com",
    "path": "/ex1",
    "params": "",
    "query": a=b&c=d,
    "fragment": ""
}
```

It's just like the inverse of the output of `urlparse.urlparse("http://for.example.com/ex1?a=b&c=d")`. Can I get the url from the dict?

Comment: Yes. Use `urllib.urlencode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlparse` generates a `ParseResult` object. Hence, just construct an object of `ParseResult` and use the `geturl()` method  to generate the URL.

```
>>> url_pattern = {
    "scheme": "http",
    "netloc": "for.example.com",
    "path": "/ex1",
    "params": "",
    "query": "a=b&c=d",
    "fragment": ""
}
>>> from urlparse import ParseResult
>>> ParseResult(**url_pattern).geturl()
'http://for.example.com/ex1?a=b&c=d'
```